# How to import and use kafka connect datagen in spark application

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We need to perform unit testing for our real time streaming application written in scala-spark.

One option is to use embedded-Kafka for kafka test case simulation.

The other option is to use kafka connect datagen - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen

The examples found on various blogs include CLI option.

What i'm looking for is an example to import kafka connect datagen within scala application.

Appreciate help on any good resource on kafka connect datagen OR simulating streaming application within scala application

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect is meant to be standalone.

You can use TestContainers project to start a broker and Connect worker, then run datagen connector from there.

Otherwise, for more rigorous testing, write your own `KafkaProducer.send` methods with data you control